# Springboot Jpa or hibernate updating records instead of inserting

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

Hi  I have a normal working application which is inserting / deleting / updating correctly. However I am trying to implement receiving a json string from ajax and inserting it in a database (PostgreSQL 10.12)

The first 2 to 5 records get inserted correctly however then the application starts updating records instead of inserting and the primary keys get out of sequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dashboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>sp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring </name>
    <description>Spring boot </description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractModel<Long extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6323358535657100144L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AbstractModel<?> other = (AbstractModel<?>) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            return other.id == null;
        } else return id.equals(other.id);
    }

}
```

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;


@Entity
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class PurchaseOrderProducts extends AbstractModel<Long> {



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5927643103467927664L;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer productcode;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String manufacturer;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String model;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String supplier;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String supplierproductcode;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer orderno;

    public Integer getProductcode() {
        return productcode;
    }

    public void setProductcode(Integer productcode) {
        this.productcode = productcode;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public String getSupplierproductcode() {
        return supplierproductcode;
    }

    public void setSupplierproductcode(String supplierproductcode) {
        this.supplierproductcode = supplierproductcode;
    }

    public Integer getOrderno() {
        return orderno;
    }

    public void setOrderno(Integer orderno) {
        this.orderno = orderno;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PurchaseOrderProducts [productcode=" + productcode + ", manufacturer=" + manufacturer + ", model="
                + model + ", supplier=" + supplier + ", supplierproductcode=" + supplierproductcode + ", orderno="
                + orderno + "]";
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class PurchaseOrdersProductsService extends AbstractService<PurchaseOrderProducts, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private PurchaseOrdersProductsRepository purchaseOrdersProductsRepository;

    @Override
    protected JpaRepository<PurchaseOrderProducts, Long> getRepository() {      
        return purchaseOrdersProductsRepository;
    }
    
    public List<PurchaseOrderProducts> getAllPurchaseOrdersProducts() {
        return getRepository().findAll();
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public boolean checkIfExists(Integer productcode, Integer orderno) {
        boolean val = false;
        Integer test = purchaseOrdersProductsRepository.checkIfExists(productcode,orderno);
        
        if(test == 0) {
            val = false;
        } else {
            val = true;
        }       
        return val;     
    }
    
    public void saveAll(List<PurchaseOrderProducts> purchaseOrderProducts) {        
        purchaseOrdersProductsRepository.saveAll(purchaseOrderProducts);        
    }
    
    
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface PurchaseOrdersProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrderProducts, Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT count(productcode) FROM purchase_order_products m WHERE m.productcode = ?1 AND m.orderno=?2" , nativeQuery=true)
    Integer checkIfExists(long productcode, long orderno);
    
}
```

```
@PostMapping(value = "/submitpoproducts", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> savePurchaseOrderProductList(@RequestBody PurchaseOrderProducts[] purchaseOrderProducts) {

        

        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < purchaseOrderProducts.length; i++) {

            // if (purchaseOrderProducts[i].getProductcode() != null) {
            // if
            // (purchaseOrdersProductsService.checkIfExists(purchaseOrderProducts[i].getProductcode(),
            // purchaseOrderProducts[i].getOrderno()) == false) {

            
            purchaseOrdersProductsService.save(purchaseOrderProducts[i]);
             
            System.out.println(purchaseOrderProducts[i].toString());
            // }
            // }
            // response.add("Saved product: " + purchaseOrderProducts[i]);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

```
PurchaseOrderProducts [productcode=10000004, manufacturer=FS, model=CL 20cl, supplier=Fs, supplierproductcode=FAR001, orderno=10000003]
```

```
 id | 
----+
  1 |
  2 |
  3 | 
  4 | 

 id | 
----+--------------
  1 | 
  3 | 
  4 | 
  2 | 
  5 |
```

Comment: I guess you are using the save() methode of spring data, if so; normally if the Id of `purchaseOrderProducts` is null the `save(purchaseOrderProducts)` will **insert** a new record to database, if the id is not null then `save(purchaseOrderProducts)` will **update** the exisitng record.

Comment: hi I cannot thank you enough it was 2 days looking into this and the id was indeed being sent in my Json. I removed it and the inserts went on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to test your issue as you didn't provide the JSON. As a best pratice, you should check the client is not sending PurchaseOrderProducts with id, this may be your issue.

Comment: Hi indeed this may be the problem. !! is there a way to push the @RequestBody to a visible output of some kind ? to be able to see my full json being received.  thanks.

Comment: I think you can test with @RequestBody String body as a parameter

Comment: hi I cannot thank you enough it was 2 days looking into this and the id was indeed being sent in my Json. I removed it and the inserts went on.

Comment: hi, you're welcome. Thanks me by accepting my answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that might come across this. I removed the json key value pair being sent having the key id and it worked. (with javascript )

delete row['id'];